# Multiple connections to the server even though i am connecting to my website from only one pc. (REACT.JS & SOCKET.IO)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I am trying to get data from one user and show the same data in real time to the other users that are using the page.I even tried to delete and remove the previous connections but same think happened.
Notice that the code below is from the App.js file(frontend) and the index.js file(backend).

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Header from "./Header";
import Footer from "./Footer";
import Note from "./Note";
import CreateArea from "./CreateArea";
import Axios from "axios";
import io from "socket.io-client";



function App() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);
  const [noteForDeletion, setNoteForDeletion] = useState(null);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.158:3001");

  async function fetchNotes() {
    const dbnotes = await Axios.get("http://192.168.1.158:1337/api/notes");
    const newNotes = [];

    dbnotes.data.data.forEach((note) => {
      newNotes.push({
        title: note.attributes.title,
        content: note.attributes.content,
        id: note.id,
      });
    });
    setNotes(newNotes);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (noteForDeletion !== null) return;
    fetchNotes();

    socket.on("receive_note", (data) => {
      alert(data.data);
    });
  }, [socket]);

  //addNote is used to add a new Note
  async function addNotesFromAPI(newNote) {
    setLoading(true);

    const data = {
      data: {
        title: newNote.title,
        content: newNote.content,
      },
    };

    try {
      const response = await Axios.post(
        "http://192.168.1.158:1337/api/notes",
        data
      );
      const newNoteData = {
        title: response.data.data.attributes.title,
        content: response.data.data.attributes.content,
        id: response.data.data.id,
      };
      //new line
      socket.emit("add_note", data);
      // console.log(newNoteData);
      
      setNotes((prevNotes) => {
        return [...prevNotes, newNoteData];
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error adding note: ", error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  //deleteNote is used to delete a Note.
  //this function is similar to the addNote() function.
  async function deleteNote(id) {
    setLoading(true);
    setNoteForDeletion(id);
    try {
      await Axios.delete(`http://192.168.1.158:1337/api/notes/${id}`);

      setNotes((prevNotes) => {
        //filter the list of the previous notes and find a note with a specific index/id
        return prevNotes.filter((noteItem) => noteItem.id !== id);
      });

      setNoteForDeletion(null);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error found: ", error);
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }

  // Component rendering.
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      <CreateArea onAdd={addNotesFromAPI} />
      {loading ? (
        <div className="loading-container">
          <div className="loading-text">Loading...</div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        notes.map((noteItem) => (
          <Note
            key={noteItem.id}
            id={noteItem.id}
            title={noteItem.title}
            content={noteItem.content}
            onDelete={() => deleteNote(noteItem.id)}
            // onEdit={() => handleEdit(noteItem.id)} // Pass the handleEdit function
          />
        ))
      )}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const http = require("http");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());

const server = http.createServer(app);
const connectedUsers = new Set();

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "http://192.168.1.158:3000",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "DELETE"],
  },
});

io.on("connection", (socket) => {
  console.log(`User Connected: ${socket.id}`);

  connectedUsers.add(socket.id);

  socket.on("add_note", (data) => {
    socket.broadcast.emit("receive_note", data);

  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(`User Disconnected: ${socket.id}`);
    // Remove the user's socket ID from the connectedUsers set
    connectedUsers.delete(socket.id);
  });

});

server.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Server is up!");
});
```

I tried to get the data from the user (the user gives the data into the front-end) to the back end and then broadcast the data to all the other users of the site without refreshing the page manualy.

Ps: this is my github account if you want to download the app and run it.
https://github.com/PanagiotisVard/KeeperApp.git

Comment: In react add `, {transports: ['websocket']}` to your connect. I had weird issues with mine and when i did that it fixed it. 
So your connect string would look like this
`const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.158:3001", {transports: ['websocket']});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had was

```
 const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.158:3001");
```

Inside the App component. I was re-rendering the page multiple times and as a result of this i was using socket again and again.

Answer (score 0):

In react add `, {transports: ['websocket']}` to your connect.

I had weird issues with mine and when i did that it fixed it.

So your connect string would look like this:

`const socket = io.connect("http://192.168.1.158:3001", {transports: ['websocket']});`